# What forms could be used for this C++/CLI application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, sudoku

[image]

The program above is, as said, a Sudoku game. I have written down ideas on how to write an algorithm for generating random boards in this Sudoku game which could actually work, but it turns out the algorithm isn't my biggest problem, the board is. I have asked several questions which told me the conclusion of re-making the board.

My question here is - What could be used as board? Originally, I had 81 buttons. Yes you read that correctly, 81 buttons. The design was good at first - you would click the button and the text on it would be incremented by one. Very friendly interface, but a pain to code. One of the solutions that came to my attention was that I could use a PaintEvent, however, I found no documentation of that alternative except with GIT, and most I found were in c sharp. I'm using C++/CLI, in Visual Studio 2010 and on Windows OS.

For further details, my board should be 9x9, this image bellow represents what my final product should look like:

[image]

What alternatives to my version could be used? If you haven't read my full post, my original design was a board made of 81 buttons (9 horizontal, 9 vertically)

Comment: How many buttons?  9 times 9 = ?

Comment: @Ben Voigt, sorry about that, wrote this post in quite a rush. Editted.

Comment: +1 for Romanian buttons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, you might create a sidebar with 0..9 numbers and the interface might be based on drag'n'drop.

The user picks a number and drags it to the selected board cell.

This is suitable for both desktop mouse-based apps and for touch-based mobile applications.

In this approach you don't need 81 buttons - just a single Panel, which accepts the 'DragDrop' event.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973845.aspx for details.

Good Luck !